# How to get m3u8 files from site? use python3

Tags: python

*Please excuse my poor English.*

I don't know m3u8 address, just know basic address
How to get m3u8 files from site? use python3

Comment: Just getting m3u8 files is the same as getting any other files—use `urllib` or `requests` or `pycurl` or whatever you prefer. But if you don't know the address, there's no way to download it. That's true for anything.

Comment: If you're asking about parsing the m3u8 file to get the addresses of all chunks, or just the chunks for a specific bandwidth—that isn't hard at all, since it's a well-defined open format, and very simple. I'm sure there are libraries that wrap that up for you if you just search PyPI. But if you're asking for someone to recommend a specific library that does it, I'm afraid StackOverflow is not the right place to ask for library recommendations.